# Trouble getting texture pixels Not to repeat at the edge

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

Not familiar with OpenGL, and cannot seem to figure out this small detail.  I keep finding information on repeats of a texture and not border elements.

When zooming in on a texture, the edge pixels on the end are repeated to the edge of the surface view that I am working on.  I would rather see a clear background behind those pixels when the texture is smaller than the view.

I can assume that it has to do with setting attributes to my texture around these lines of the code, but I just can't follow it enough to understand what changes to make to get the desired result.

```
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Aide on the (most likely quick modification) topic for getting that desired result would put my current issue to rest.

[image: Repeating edge pixels behind the texture]

Comment: How do you perform the zooming? It would seem that you tangle with the texture coordinates to do so.. which would indeed result in such an image.

Comment: Yes, a translation matrix is multiplied onto the gl_FragColor, but I was under the assumption that there is an attribute somewhere that defines what gets drawn in a situation when extra pixels needed to fill extra space; such as the repeating edge pixels shown here.  If it is something deeper than just a setting, then that would be unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'll try to explain.

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

The `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is the filter applied when a texture's bitmap dimension in larger than the drawing surface's corresponding dimension. `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` is the opposite. So this is not the problem.

`GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` however, define what to do when a texture coordinate falls outside of the 0.0 to 1.0 range (For both axis). You have them both set to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`, which basicly means that if a texture coordinate < 0 then use 0, if > 1 use 1. This is basicly what you see happening in your picture.

However, this can only be changed to `GL_REPEAT` which repeats the texture or `GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT` which repeats and mirrors. So your problem can not be fixed by changing these settings. There is no discard-if-out-of-range setting, which I think you need.
You can read more about this in the documentation if you please: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/

I don't know exactly how you zoom, but it usually doesn't involve changing texture coordinates as far as I know. If you want to keep it this way, you could try a little hack though - in the the fragment shader you could add before setting the `gl_FragColor`:

```
   if (tc.x < 0.0 || tc.x > 1.0 || tc.y < 0.0 || tc.y > 1.0 ) 
     discard;
```

Where tc is your texture coordinate. So this would discard the fragment if the texture coordinate is out of the 0 to 1 range.

It's not a pretty solution, but it should do the trick.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Thought there would have been something there that I was just missing to change the way that it clipped.  Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 2):

Brianberg's approach would work, but scaling the quad you're rendering the image to rather than modifying texture coordinates would be a cleaner & better performing solution. There's no need to change the texture coordinates, as you always want the image to fit the quad exactly.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to do some more thought on this then.  It goes a bit further than this small question since it is really an Android application in the background and this would involve dealing with the SurfaceView at that point as well.  Was just hoping for an OpenGL attribute solution for a quick fix on the issue.